# Why does this inequality stand?

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms, integral-inequality

I want to ask something about:

"Since $i \log_e i$ is concave upwards, it is easy to show that $$\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} i \log_e i \leq \int_2^n x \log_e x \,dx \leq \frac{n^2 \log_e n}{2}-\frac{n^2}{4}$$"

$i \log_e i$ is concave upwards because the second derivative of $i \log_e i$ is positive. Correct?

Can you explain the inquality? I don't understand how we show it?

Comment: I think the important thing here is that $x \log x$ is nondecreasing on $[2, \infty)$. Therefore if you replace $x$ by $\mathrm{floor}(x)$ in the integral, you get something smaller, namely the sum on the left.

Comment: "concave upwards"? you mean convex?

Comment: @user2345215 In my book it is "concave upwards". Is this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint1:** (for left inequality)

$f(x)=x\ln x$ is increasing on $[2,\infty)$ and

$$\int_2^nf(x)\,dx = \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} \int_i^{i+1}f(x)\,dx \geq \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} f(i).$$

**Hint2:** (for right inequality) $$\int x\ln x \,dx = F(x) + C$$

where 
$$ F(x)= \frac{1}{2}x^2\ln x-\frac{1}{4}x^2,$$

and $$F(2) >0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Convexity is not really needed, we can just use partial summation and the inequality $\frac{2}{2n+1}\leq\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq\frac{1}{n}$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}n\log n = \frac{N(N-1)}{2}\log N-\sum_{n=1}^{N-2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right),$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq\sum_{n=1}^{N-2}\frac{n+1}{2}=\frac{N^2-N-2}{4},$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\geq\sum_{n=1}^{N-2}\frac{n^2+n}{2n+1}\\=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{N-2}\left(2n+1-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)\geq\frac{3N^2-7N+2}{12}.$$